# How can I replace linebreaks?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to remove multiple linefeeds from a string however the string remains with them. Here's my code:

```
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, ControlChars.NewLine)
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.NewLine)
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.CrLf, ControlChars.NewLine)
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.NewLine & ControlChars.NewLine & ControlChars.NewLine, ControlChars.NewLine)
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.NewLine & ControlChars.NewLine, ControlChars.NewLine)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, "%n%")
str = str.Replace(ControlChars.Cr, "%n%")

str = str.Replace("%n%%n%", "%n%")
str = str.Replace("%n%", ControlChars.NewLine)
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. I couldn't make it work. your code can't remove the lines.